# Returning BufferedImage destroys the image

Tags: java, swing

I have a methode which returns a buffered image, inside the method the image is ok. But as soon as I try to invoke the methode and display the returned image, it gets corrupted.

```
public BufferedImage componentToImage(Component component, Rectangle region)
        throws IOException {

    GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment
        .getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
    GraphicsDevice gd = ge.getDefaultScreenDevice();
    GraphicsConfiguration gc = gd.getDefaultConfiguration();

    BufferedImage bImage = gc.createCompatibleImage(component.getWidth(),

    component.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

    Graphics2D g = bImage.createGraphics();

    component.paint(g);

    g.setColor(component.getForeground());
    g.setFont(component.getFont());

    return bImage;
}
```

Code to display image:

```
BufferedImage bi = componentToImage(jchartpanel);
ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon();
icon.setImage(bi);
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, icon);
```

If I run the display image code inside the method it works, but the returned image does not display.

Comment: So you're drawing a component to an image, how are you checking that it is ok? And in what way is it corrupted? Btw, shouldn't you call the setters on the graphics object before calling `component.paint(g)`?

Comment: do `ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(bi);` doesn't works?

Comment: I have tried to display it and write it to a file, if that worked I assumed it's okay. Writing and displaying works only in componentToImage(). As soon as I work with the returned value, it donts gets drawn or saved. But no exception is thrown either.
Initializing the ImageIcon with the image directly dont works either.

Comment: `If I run the display image code inside the method it works, but the returned image does not display.` - post your [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem.